# How can I type a § in a Microsoft Remote Desktop Connection window?

Tags: keyboard, remote-desktop, internationalization

How can I type a "§" in a [Microsoft Remote Desktop Connection](http://www.microsoft.com/mac/remote-desktop-client) (RDC) window? I am using the OS X client software to connect remotely to a computer running Microsoft Windows. In OS X <kbd>Option ⌥</kbd>+<kbd>6</kbd> produces the symbol I want to be sent to the remote computer.

Comment: bopritchard, it would be helpful to explain in your question what "RDC" is and not to assume that everybody understands the acronym. You should explain what the program is and what it is used for. I added this for you.

Comment: Alt+0167 is the character code for the Section Symbol.

Comment: And, bopritchard, welcome to AskDifferent!

Answer (score 2):

Here is the easiest  way to do this. You can copy and paste characters and text between the Mac and the remote Windows session.

On the Mac, open a word processor and type `Option-6` to get the "§" character.

`Copy` this character.

Click on the Microsoft Remote Desktop Client window, click in a word processor on the Windows computer you are connecting to, and `Paste`. The "§" character will be pasted into your word processor document.

**If on the other hand you want to learn how to type various special characters on Windows while using Microsoft Remote Desktop Client on a Mac,** here is what you must do.

If you don't want to memorize Windows character codes (such as Alt-0167 as @OghmaOsiris explained above) you can select an alternate software keyboard layout on the Windows computer. On the Windows computer, select the `United States-International` keyboard. Then you can type `Ctrl-Alt-Shift S` to produce the "§" symbol.

[image]

To set  this up on Windows 7, go to `Control Panel` and select `Region and Language`. Under the `Keyboards and Languages` tab, click the `Change Keyboards` button. Click the Add button and you can select the United States-International option among many others.

If you select more than one keyboard layout, you can switch between them on the fly by enabling the Language Bar, either floating on the screen or docked in the taskbar.

To look at all the character options in each keyboard layout, use the `On-Screen Keyboard` app in Windows 7.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you saying that the answer is not possible to generate on the Mac keyboard and instead the user has to use a software keyboard on screen through the remote connection?

Comment: I have amended my answer with the "quick and easy" method, but left my extensive explanation on the "thorough" method after it.

Comment: Vote worthy, a very nice summary.

Comment: With the work that I do in classical music, often I have to type words or phrases in several different human languages (English, French, German, Italian, Spanish, and more) on both Mac and Windows. So I know a lot about this subject.

Comment: Alt+0167 does not work from the MacBook keyboard. Only from a full size.